# Oracle SQL with java. Updating Database statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
public boolean executeUpdate() throws SQLException {
        String updateString= "UPDATE CLIENTE SET ID_PLANO= ? WHERE ID_CLIENTE= ? ;";
        PreparedStatement statment = null;
        int result=0;
        try {
            v_conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            statment = v_conn.prepareStatement(updateString);
            statment.setInt(1, 1);
            statment.setInt(2, 1);
            result=statment.executeUpdate();
            v_conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            if (v_conn != null) {
                try {
                    System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                    v_conn.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException excep) {
                    System.out.println(excep.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (statment != null) {
                statment.close();
            }
            v_conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        if (result == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This piece of code cannot update my database, do you know why?
The statement script runs perfectly in SQL.
Can you help me?

I'm freaking out with the time i am spending here.

Comment: Can you add the SQL statement that you feed into your executeUpdate method?

Comment: One reason for that may be that you store the SQL statement in a filed `v_str` which you use in `v_stmt.executeUpdate(v_str)`. There is no guarantee that when executing the statement it is the same as the one concatenated in the `updateAtributoTabela` method. What you can do is pass the update statement as a parameter to `executeUpdate`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: please use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: See the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Code Update @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: What is the return value in 'result'. ? It is possible that it is returning '0' which means where clause is not matched

Comment: there should not be any semicolon `;` at the end of SQL statement.